# TSQL - how to find if a column has a space char(32)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

TSQL - how to find if a column has a space `char(32)`?

```
select *
from [sometable]
where CHARINDEX(' ', [somecolumn]) > 0
```

doesn't work?  Any ideas?

Comment: What values work and what fail?

Comment: What type is field somecolumn?

Answer (score 16):

You have to rtrim CHAR columns.

CHAR columns are padded with spaces on the right up to the maximum length.

RTRIM helps to avoid false positives when storing strings that are shorter than the maximum length.

```
select * from [table] where rtrim(col) like '% %'



create table dropme
(foo char(32))

insert into dropme values('nospaces')
insert into dropme values('i have a space')
insert into dropme values('space bar')

select replace(foo,' ','|') from dropme
where foo like '% %'
```

---

```
nospaces
i|have|a|space
space|bar

select replace(foo,' ','|') from dropme
where rtrim(foo) like '% %'
```

---

```
i|have|a|space
space|bar
```

Comment: and `ltrim()` as in `rtrim(ltrim(col))`?

Comment: @CodeBlend CHAR columns are padded with spaces on the right up to the maximum length. RTRIM helps to avoid false positives when storing strings that are shorter than the maximum length. LTRIM doesn't help avoid that, and might actually cause false negatives if you want to find spaces at the start of a value.

Answer (score 7):

The following example should illustrate how you can achieve this.

```
create table #tableTest
(
    someData varchar(100) not null
);

insert into #tableTest(someData) values('dsadsa');
insert into #tableTest(someData) values('fdssf 432423');
insert into #tableTest(someData) values('432423fsdv');
insert into #tableTest(someData) values('321 jhlhkj 543');



select * 
from #tableTest;

select * 
from #tableTest 
where charindex(char(32),someData) > 0;

drop table #tableTest;
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Both ways work for me:

```
SELECT ''''+a+'''' FROM(
SELECT 'asd fgh' AS a UNION ALL
SELECT ' fgh' AS a UNION ALL
SELECT 'asd ' AS a UNION ALL
SELECT 'asfdg') As t
WHERE a LIKE '% %'

---------
'asd fgh'
' fgh'
'asd '

SELECT ''''+a+'''' FROM(
SELECT 'asd fgh' AS a UNION ALL
SELECT ' fgh' AS a UNION ALL
SELECT 'asd ' AS a UNION ALL
SELECT 'asfdg') As t
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', a) > 0

---------
'asd fgh'
' fgh'
'asd '
```

Comment: Wasn't an exact fix for my predicament, but certainly got me closer to a solution. This way of presenting it struck a chord with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
PrdPicture LIKE '%'+char(160)+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you've not really explained what the problem is...

Are you looking for `hardspace (nbsp)`, `CHAR(160)`? Or `tab CHAR(9)`?
These can look like spaces but aren't

Answer (score 1):

Use below query:

```
SELECT UniqueName 
FROM employee
WHERE employeeName LIKE '% %'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from [sometable] where somecolumn like '% %'
```

Comment: Interesting.  It doesn't work.  For a char column, it returns all rows.  For varchar it works as you'd expect.

Comment: @Joe. CHAR columns are space padded, because they are fixed size.

Comment: im that case i would think the OP would need to RTRIm the column first select * from [sometable] where rtrim(somecolumn) like '% %'

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question as worded, though I was looking to see if the column had a space vs being null.  This worked for me:

```
SELECT UniqueName 
FROM employee
WHERE ascii(employeeName) = 32
```

The intuitive query doesn't work; below returns all null rows as well:

```
SELECT UniqueName 
FROM employee
WHERE employeeName = ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions as often underrated:

```
select * from [sometable] where somecolumn like '%[ ][^ ]%'
```

`[ ]` is the condition for spaces while `[^ ]` is to avoid looking for string which has two consecutive spaces.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-ver16